# capture hyperlink click java SWT

Tags: java, swt

I've set up just a browser implementation to view a webpage. I cannot figure out how to capture hyperlink clicks. If I click on a link nothing happens.

I've tried Listener, LocationListener and applied to shell, display, browserWindowGroup and browser but no response to hyperlink click.

UPDATE: This is specifically related to http://inbox.google.com. I can click hyperlinks elsewhere, just not from within the body of a message in Google Inbox.

```
    import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
    import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
    import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
    import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

    public class BrowserTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Browser Test");
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        Group browserWindowGroup = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
        browserWindowGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        browserWindowGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        final Browser browser = new Browser(browserWindowGroup, SWT.NONE);
        browser.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        shell.setSize(1280, 800);
        shell.open();
        browser.setUrl("http://inbox.google.com");
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for providing a runnable example!
I found a solution at https://deanoneclipse.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/intercepting-links/

You need to add a `LocationListener`, like this

```
    browser.addLocationListener(new LocationListener() {
        public void changing(LocationEvent event) {
            System.out.println(event);            
        }

        public void changed(LocationEvent event) {
        }
    });
```

making your full class look like this

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.LocationEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.LocationListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class BrowserTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Browser Test");
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        Group browserWindowGroup = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
        browserWindowGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        browserWindowGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        final Browser browser = new Browser(browserWindowGroup, SWT.NONE);
        browser.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        browser.addLocationListener(new LocationListener() {
            public void changing(LocationEvent event) {
                    System.out.println(event);
            }

            public void changed(LocationEvent event) {
            }
        });

        shell.setSize(1280, 800);
        shell.open();
        browser.setUrl("http://www.google.com");
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, Listener and LocationListener are still not responding using http://inbox.google.com. I can get at links in other pages I have tried.